# A simple php/mysql script to manage folder access?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I'm in need of a solution to allow clients access to physical folders.

My first intention was to manually control this by using a .htpasswd file, but I was curious if any of you have come across a solution that already exists.

Something that would allow an admin to create users with passwords, and create physical folders for those users.

Answer (score 0):

We have an application that stores paths in relation to users. So by default all paths are blocked. But we grant each user access to a path in our table. Then when a page is accessed we check to see if there is a record in our database for a user to have access to that particular page/path.

In coldfusion this can be done in the onRequest method before any page processing is done. You could do it on the page itself I guess. Are you looking for a plugin or just a way to do it?

Comment: I was more wondering if there is a preexisting script that does it. I know how to do it in php/mysql, but I hate reinventing the wheel.

Comment: All I know of is using something like a framework. I use Wheels, but I think with Zend all the structure is there.